# Display images using the Node.js Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

So I have a first run dialog that asks the user to upload a photo. I do this via:

`builder.Prompts.attachment(session, "Thanks. Now upload a picture").`

and then in the next part of the waterfall, saving the uploaded media to `session.userData` like so:

```
function(session, results) {
    //some other code
    builder.Prompts.attachment(session, "Thanks. Now upload a picture.");
},
function(session, results) {
    session.userData.profilePhoto = results.response;
    session.endDialog("All done.")
}
```

So, say I know want to display that photo. How would I do it?

I've tried sending a `HeroCard` with a `CardImage`:

```
var message = new builder.Message(session);

var att = new builder.HeroCard(session)
        .images([
            builder.CardImage.create(session, session.userData.profilePhoto)
        ])
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, "http://google.com", "buttonText")
        ]);

message.addAttachment(att);
session.send(message)
```

but that didn't work (I also tried to do `session.userData.profilePhoto.contentUrl` for the CardImage but that didnt work as well).

How exactly am I suppose to display images?

Answer (score 1):

UserData is not intended to store large objects, only state.  Data bags are limited to 64k.  You'll want to use your own storage mechanism for images.

Comment: Ok, but even then, how would I display those stored images? Would I need to store them in some kind of database that gives me a URL and pass that into a `CardImage`? The Node.js documentation currently has no guides written on images, so I'm looking for some general info on displaying images with my bot.

Comment: Azure Blog Storage has a node.js library that is pretty straightforward.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/